# Handle exceptions without crashing Server Socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am doing Socket Programming , in that many client connecting to server , and server has to be keep on running so that any client can connect at any time . My problem is handling Exception in server socket. If any msg comming from client is not formatted server will throw exception , in that case server throws Exception and it stops. But I need Server shd keep on running.How to solve this,

Here is my server code ,

```
 public class SimpleServer extends Thread {
 private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
 private Socket s1=null;
 InputStream s1In=null;
 DataInputStream dis=null;
 OutputStream out=null;
 DataOutputStream dos=null;
 SimpleServer()
    {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1231);
            this.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             System.out.println("Exception on new ServerSocket: " + ex);
        }
    }

  public void run()
    {


        while(true){
            try {

                 System.out.println("Waiting for connect to client");
                 s1=serverSocket.accept();


                 s1In = s1.getInputStream();
                 dis = new DataInputStream(s1In);

                 out=s1.getOutputStream();
                 dos=new DataOutputStream(out);

                 String clientData=dis.readUTF();
                 System.out.println(clientData);

                 String[] data=clientData.split("#");

                 String msg_type =data[0];
                 String busId=data[1];  // Here it may throw ArrayIndexoutofBoundException

               //My other codding Stuff
                 dos.writeUTF("Bus Registered Successfully");
                 dos.flush();
                 s1.close();


              }
              catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.println("Exception in while " +ex.getMessage());
                try {
                    s1.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception is: "+e);
                try {
                    s1.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

      }

 }
```

How to Solve this problem , Once it throw exception the Server will Stop , How to keep the Server running? Can anyone Help me in this please

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the return statements from your catch block

Comment: I removed return and close the socket but the problem is, it accept continously by only one client , it is not allowing another client to connect

Comment: Please post the complete code. Where is the definition of variable "s1"? Are you closing your streams?

Comment: @mithradir Please check my updated question. I am not closing the stream , I m just writing and flushing it .

Comment: I guess you need to create a new Thread to handle the processing for each client/request. Check this tutorial (at the bottom): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: @Raghu your code seems to be OK; I've tested here; nothing wrong. the server does not stops working

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle each accepted connection with a client in a separate thread. Using java 7 ExecutorService and a bit java 8 lambda code  it would look something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleServer {
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    SimpleServer() {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1231)) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connect to client");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new ConnectionHandler(socket).startInThread();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception on new ServerSocket: " + ex);
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionHandler {
        private final Socket socket;

        private ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        private void handle() {
            try {
                InputStream s1In = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s1In);

                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

                String clientData = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println(clientData);

                String[] data = clientData.split("#");

                String msg_type = data[0];
                String busId = data[1];

                dos.writeUTF("Bus Registered Successfully");
                dos.flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.print("Exception: ");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.print("Exception on socket.close()");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private void startInThread() {
            executorService.execute(this::handle);
        }
    }
}
```